# I am Ghoi vaishya and my gotra is gangal i am trying to find my sage and kuldevta. any help would be really awesome!

Tags: rishi, gotra

I am Ghoi vaishya and my gotra is gangal i am trying to find my orignal rishi and kuldevta. any help would be really awesome!